# How to get Make to find & recurse sub-dirs without their own Makefiles?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a project consisting of multiple sub-dirs, each of which contains one or more markdown files.  I want to build various target docs from the .md sources using [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/).  I'm trying to figure out how to get Make to (a) find and (b) recurse all the sub-dirs automatically.  Right now the Makefile is as follows:

```
clean:
    -rm -rf $(RSTS)

RSTS := $(patsubst notes/%.md, notes/%.rst, $(wildcard notes/*.md))
%.rst: %.md
    pandoc $< -f markdown -t rst -o $@

md2rst: $(RSTS)

.PHONY: clean $(RSTS)
```

Which works: however I would have to list each of the sub-dirs explicitly.  I know it should be possible to list the sub-dirs using something like `DIRS := $(wildcard */)`.  But I can't quite get it all to stitch together.

Note there are no makefiles in the sub-dirs: just want to run the md --> rst conversion on all .md files in all sub dirs.

Apologies if answered elsewhere: couldn't find it.  Pointers welcomed if so.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear if you're trying to look one level deep only, but if so you can just use:

```
RSTS := $(patsubst %.md,%.rst,$(wildcard */*.md))
```

Comment: Nesting is only 1 level so that's perfect - thanks.  Too embroiled in finding a recursive solution to see the simple one...